# Take data from a Google sheet with Google App Script and organize it in a Google doc

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

In Sheets I have dates and events that I would like to publish in Docs with the events listed under MONTH - YEAR. The number of events can vary, though usually over 400 events over a 2 year period.  Sheets has them all sorted, but I haven't programmed in JavaScript before as I have used Access to do this in the past (But it seems to be overkill to have Access just for this.)  It seems that Google App Script is the only way to do it?

A sample of the Sheet is here https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IYmdIZU9wEVgSr7l4UWzJE7xXgUEQQOHUVarBHCeWgI/edit?usp=sharing

A sample of the doc that I would like to make is here https://docs.google.com/document/d/1obF-OiRAQG_6WxwiCT5-GkvnjETsdYiMHB2SDGxDeKA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I don't follow links to spreadsheets or documents.

Comment: Your links are not public so there's a good chance nobody will use them.  Actually, there's a pretty that no one will use them anyway.

Comment: Sorry,I thought the links were public. Hopefully I got that changed now.

Answer (score 1):

From the question

> It seems that Google App Script is the only way to do it?

Besides Google Apps Script, there are APIs for Google Sheets and Google Docs that you could  use with several programming languages. For more details see

- https://developers.google.com/docs
- https://developers.google.com/sheets

Comment: Yes, it looks like a Google Docs API would be the way to go. Thanks.